# Custom Serializer Not Called For Array Or Collection Types

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson

I am writing a spring boot command line tool that is supposed to interface with an API backend I already implemented. That API backend is built with spring data rest with the hateoas package, so it produces HAL message types.

In my CLI tool, I want to POST an entity that contains a list of other entities (one to many relation). For easier use, I wanted to use Resource types in the models to express relations and have a JSON serializer to transform the Resources into only their self hrefs.

My serializer works fine for one to one relations, but never gets calls to serialize arrays or any collection types.

This is what the API accepts when I POST an entity:

```
{
  "property1": "value1",
  "myrelation" : "http://localhohst:8080/relatedentities/1"
  "mycollection": [
    "http://localhost:8080/otherrelatedentities/2",
    "http://localhost:8080/otherrelatedentities/3"
  ]
}
```

On the CLI side, I created a model entity in the CLI application like this:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class MyEntity {
  private String property1;

  @JsonSerialize(using = HateoasResourceIdSerializer.class)
  private Resource<RelatedEnity> myrelation;

  @JsonSerialize(using = HateoasResourceIdSerializer.class)
  private List<Resource<OtherRelatedEntity>> mycollection;
}
```

I wrote this HateoasResourceIdSerializer to transform any Resource type into only its self href:

```
public class HateoasResourceIdSerializer extends StdSerializer<Resource<?>> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HateoasResourceIdSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public HateoasResourceIdSerializer(Class<Resource<?>> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Resource<?> value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value.getId().getHref());
    }

}
```

Looking at the payload sent to the API backend, I can see that the "myrelation" property is set to the URL of the target entity while the "mycollection" property is always null.

I tried writing a 2nd Serializer that would accept `Collection<Resource<?>>` but that didnt get called either.

My expectation would be that the serializer above for Resource would be applied to arrays as well as any collection type.

**EDIT:**
I was asked to provide code to register serializers, so here it is. I added the two mixins as suggested in one of the answers below (hope I did it right) but did not see the expected behavior. I also assumed that due to the registration I could remove the `@JsonSerialize(using = HateoasResource(s)IdSerializer.class)` annotation from the properties. The current behavior is that those properties do not get rendered at all.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type=EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SwissArmyKnifeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        // ...
    }

    @Autowired
    private HalHttpMessageConverter halHttpMessageConverter;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(halHttpMessageConverter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class HalHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    public HalHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(new ObjectMapper(), new MediaType("application", "hal+json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        objectMapper
                .setHandlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(new DefaultRelProvider(), null, null));
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        objectMapper.addMixIn(Resource.class, ResourceMixIn.class);
        objectMapper.addMixIn(Resources.class, ResourcesMixIn.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ResourceSupport.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `ObjectMapper` from `HalHttpMessageConverter` is used in your case? `HalHttpMessageConverter` is a regular component and you should use `@Component` annotation instead of `@Configuration`. When you register global `MixIn` you can delete annotations from properties in `MyEntity` class. I guess, `Spring` uses another `ObjectMapper` which is a common problem: [How to enable 'ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS' feature to allow leading zeroes in JSON Request Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795970/how-to-enable-allow-numeric-leading-zeros-feature-to-allow-leading-zeroes-in-j)

Comment: No I am not sure. How could I found out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly register your custom serialiser using `MixIn` feature. Instead of annotating property, you need to annotate class which informs `Jackson` you want to use it in all scenarios, not only for `MyEntity` class.

Create `MixIn` interface:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = HateoasResourceIdSerializer.class)
interface ResourceMixIn {
}
```

And register it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addMixIn(Resource.class, ResourceMixIn.class).build();
```

See other questions how to configure `Jackson` mapper in `Spring`:

- [How do i use Jackson Json parsing in a spring project without any annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104435/how-do-i-use-jackson-json-parsing-in-a-spring-project-without-any-annotations)
- [Different JSON configuration in a Spring application for REST and Ajax serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691765/different-json-configuration-in-a-spring-application-for-rest-and-ajax-serializa)
- [Spring Boot custom serializer for Collection class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240648/spring-boot-custom-serializer-for-collection-class)
- [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format)

Comment: I edited the post above adding the requested parts of the code. Please also see there for the results of suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including code to indicate how you are registering serializer for your type so that could give the clue. But custom serializers definitely should be called for array, `Collection` and `Map` values as well as simple property values.
Registering separate serializer for `Collection<Type>` is not needed (and is actually bit trickier to do: possible, but more work due to nested type) and is not meant to be done just to support specific type in collection (but rather to support more special `Collection`s, if any).

So please include code related to registration, as well as version of Jackson used (and obv. if not recent one, consider upgrading it first to see problem still persists).

Comment: Done. Please see above.

Comment: Ok. So, while this should work (and is supported way), more commonly `Module`s are used to register additional serializers and deserializers. `SimpleModule`, for example, has `addSerializer()` method; and modules are registered using `ObjectMapper.registerModule(module)`.